# How can I get the text inside two vertical bars with php regex

Tags: php, regex, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to get the text inside two vertical bars of json string.I'm parsing wikipedia data and new to json.The structure is weird.Any help?

```
 {{Infobox အတ္ထုပ္ပတ္တိ
 | အမည် =စိုးသူ 
 | ဓာတ်ပုံ =Soe Thu.jpg
 | သက်တမ်း = 
 | မွေးသက္ကရာဇ် = [[နိုဝင်ဘာ]] ၃၀ ရက်
 | အမည်ရင်း =စိုးသူလွင် 
 | မိဘအမည် =ဦးခင်မောင်လွင်+ဒေါ်ခင်သူဇာ
 | မွေးဖွားရာဒေသ= 
 | နိုင်ငံသား =[[Image:Flag of Myanmar.png|25px]] မြန်မာ
 | လူမျိုး =ဗမာ
 | ကိုးကွယ်သည့်ဘာသာ =ဗုဒ္ဓဘာသာ
 | ပညာအရည်အချင်း = M.B;B.S
 | အလုပ်အကိုင် = ဆရာဝန် ရုပ်ရှင်သရုပ်ဆောင်၊ အဆိုတော်
 | ကြင်ဖော် = ခင်မြမြဝတ်မှုန်ဆွေ
 | သားသမီး =
 | ထင်ပေါ်ကျော်ကြားမှု =အကယ်ဒမီရ မင်းသား
 | ထင်ရှားသည့်လက်ရာများ=
 | ရရှိခဲ့သည့်ဘွဲ့တံဆိပ်များ=မြန်မာ့ ရုပ်ရှင် ထူးချွန်ဆု
 | ကွယ်လွန်ရက် =
 | ကွယ်လွန်ရာဒေသ=
 | လက်မှတ်=
 | ကွန်ယက် =http://www.facebook.com/pages/Soe-Thu
  }}
```

I've tried this in php.

```
 $result=explode("|",$str);
  var_dump($result);
```

But I don't think it is a correct way.

Comment: here.. exploding is probably a better solution than regex..

Comment: This is certainly no valid JSON.

Comment: nope.I think regex have more control.

Comment: Yes.It's just part of the json. @cars10

Comment: It would be a lot smarter to fix the import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this regex

```
(?<=\|)[^|]+(?=\|)
```

check the demo [Here](https://regex101.com/r/yY5oR1/1)

I noticed that you have this text `[[Image:Flag of Myanmar.png|25px]]`

so you can use this regex also ,  because `|` in `Myanmar.png|25px` may cause problems in your case

```
(?<=\|).+?(?=\|\W)
```

check this Demo [Here](https://regex101.com/r/yY5oR1/2)

Comment: If you want the first bit, directly after the `{{` too you could change the regexp to `(?<=[\|]|\{\{)([^|]+)(?=\||\}\})`. I also added groupings `()` around the portions found.

Comment: and you can make it like this also `[^{|]+(?=\|)`

Comment: Great.Also,I would like to know how to get the text inside brackets.Eg double square bracket [[text]],curly brackets {}.